How to apply NavHost custom transition animation in jetpack compose android app
I'm implementing the new model of the Android NavHost navigation system. However, I can not resolve how to apply the custom transition animation,
Here's my implemented navhost,
AndroidNavigationTheme {
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = HomeScreen,
    ){
        composable<HomeScreen>{
            HomeScreen(
                onClickGoAboutScreen = {
                    navController.navigate(AboutScreen)
                }
            )
        }

        composable<AboutScreen>{
            AboutScreen(
                onClickGoContentScreen = {
                    navController.navigate(ContentScreen)
                }
            )
        }

        composable<ContentScreen>{
            ContentScreen(
                onClickGoHomeScreen = {
                    navController.navigate(HomeScreen)
                }
            )
        }
    }

}


@Serializable
object HomeScreen

@Serializable
object AboutScreen

@Serializable
object ContentScreen


And here's my code for the transition animation,
fun scaleIntoContainer(
    direction: ScaleTransitionDirection = ScaleTransitionDirection.INWARDS,
    initialScale: Float = if (direction == ScaleTransitionDirection.OUTWARDS) 0.9f else 1.1f
): EnterTransition {
    return scaleIn(
        animationSpec = tween(220, delayMillis = 90),
        initialScale = initialScale
    ) + fadeIn(animationSpec = tween(220, delayMillis = 90))
}

fun scaleOutOfContainer(
    direction: ScaleTransitionDirection = ScaleTransitionDirection.OUTWARDS,
    targetScale: Float = if (direction == ScaleTransitionDirection.INWARDS) 0.9f else 1.1f
): ExitTransition {
    return scaleOut(
        animationSpec = tween(
            durationMillis = 220,
            delayMillis = 90
        ), targetScale = targetScale
    ) + fadeOut(tween(delayMillis = 90))
}

enum class ScaleTransitionDirection {
    INWARDS,
    OUTWARDS
}

I'm not too fond of the default transition that the Navhost provided, If possible also suggest some good transition animation too.

This question is similar to: Navigation Compose animation is always using the default transition. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

My implementation is called Type-safe navigation, But your mentioned problem isn't.

You can still use the same parameters to pass the animations

I tried, its not working

The new typesafe composable function still offers parameters for custom transitions:
inline fun <T : Any> NavGraphBuilder.composable(
    typeMap: Map<KType, NavType<*>> = emptyMap(),
    deepLinks: List<NavDeepLink> = emptyList(),
    noinline enterTransition: (AnimatedContentTransitionScope<NavBackStackEntry>.() -> EnterTransition)? = null,
    noinline exitTransition: (AnimatedContentTransitionScope<NavBackStackEntry>.() -> ExitTransition)? = null,
    noinline popEnterTransition: (AnimatedContentTransitionScope<NavBackStackEntry>.() -> EnterTransition)? = enterTransition,
    noinline popExitTransition: (AnimatedContentTransitionScope<NavBackStackEntry>.() -> ExitTransition)? = exitTransition,
    noinline sizeTransform: (AnimatedContentTransitionScope<NavBackStackEntry>.() -> SizeTransform)? = null,
    noinline content: @Composable AnimatedContentScope.(NavBackStackEntry) -> Unit
): Unit

You can simply apply them as follows:
composable<HomeScreen>(
    enterTransition = {
        scaleIntoContainer()
    },
    exitTransition = {
        scaleOutOfContainer()
    }
) {
    HomeScreen(
        onClickGoAboutScreen = {
            navController.navigate(AboutScreen)
        }
    )
}

If the animation does not occur in your case, please double-check your animation and how you are calling it. I just verified with these two simple animations that it works on androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.8.1:
fun scaleIntoContainer(): EnterTransition {
    return slideInHorizontally(
        animationSpec = tween(2000),
        initialOffsetX = { fullWidth -> fullWidth }
    )
}

fun scaleOutOfContainer(): ExitTransition {
    return slideOutHorizontally(
        animationSpec = tween(2000),
        targetOffsetX = { fullWidth -> -fullWidth }
    )
}

